# How to prove that $\ \zeta(2)= \pi^{2} \,/\, 6\;$ using Poisson summation formula?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I use the Poisson summation formula to prove that $\zeta(2)= \pi^{2} \,/\, 6$ ?
Using the Fourier transform of $\exp\left(-\left\lvert ax \right\rvert \right)$ gives a direct expression for the series $\frac{1}{ a^2+n^2 }$ but il can't find a way to prove it for the $1\,/\,n^2$ series.

Comment: Before asking any question on how to prove $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$, be sure to check http://secamlocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf where Robin Chapman collected many proofs.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2) is a long list of ways to prove it. Maybe it's in there (but I could not find it).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just checked it and could not find it neither

Comment: http://www.libragold.com/blog/2014/12/poisson-summation-formula-and-basel-problem/